# Determine whether Office 365 password needs changing

Tags: powershell, microsoft-office-365, entra-id

How can I determine whether an Office 365 / Azure Active Directory user account's password is currently expired / required to be changed?

Answer (score 2):

There was a script for PowerShell, which creates a report of passwords that are expiring within the specified time, and already expired. https://community.spiceworks.com/scripts/show/1733-report-passwordexpiring

Comment: That seems to be for Active Directory, rather than Azure Active Directory / Office 365.

Answer (score 1):

For the password policy of Azure AD or Office365, the default password expiry duration is 90 days, and the default password expiry notification is 14 days. More information about the password policies, you may refer to the following article.

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/active-directory-passwords-policy

Also, to determine the password expiry date of specific user account, you can get the information of the last password change time stamp by using the command below in Azure AD PowerShell, and then calculate the expiry date based on the last password change time stamp.

```
Get-MsolUser
```

Comment: That requires that you manually retrieve the password policy and only accounts for scheduled expiration, rather than manual expiration (admin setting a temporary password).

Answer (score 1):

This script might helpful for people who searches this thread for a solution.

https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/Export-Office-365-Users-91b4fc50

Using this script, you can generate 7 different password reports.

- Pwd Last Change Date Report
- Pwd Expiry Date Report
- Pwd Expired Users Report
- Pwd Never Expires Users Report
- Soon-to-Expire Pwd Users Report
- Recently Pwd Changed Users Report
- Password Report for Licensed Users

Comment: Since the TechNet gallery is under deprecation, you can download the script firectly from the source blog: https://o365reports.com/2020/02/17/export-office-365-users-last-password-change-date-to-csv/